# Live video streaming in web application

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to integrate some features like Live video streaming, Video chat, Video conferencing, related features as well. I want to integrate it in a PHP codeigniter project.

I am not acknowledged about the server configuration that is required if i use http://www.videowhisper.com/?p=RTMP+Applications. I was trying a bit to integrate videowhisper plugin. When I am entering into the plugin then it says 'RTMP Server: NetConnection.Connect.Failed'.

It will be highly appreciated if anyone worked on such feature before; can help me out.

Thanks in advance

Nandinee

Answer (score 2):

I am not saying that you have to abandon PHP, but you need different technologies here.

Let's start off simple (without Akamai :-)) and think about the implications here. Video, chat, etc. - it's all client-side in the beginning. The user has a webcam, you want to grab the signal somehow and send it to the server. There is no PHP so far.

I know that Flash supports this though (check this tutorial on webcams and flash) so you could use Flash to transport the content to the server. I think if you'll stay with Flash, then Flex (flex and webcam tutorial) is probably a good idea to look into.

So those are just the basics, maybe it gives you an idea of where you need to research because obviously this won't give you a full video chat inside your app yet. For starters, you will need some sort of way to record the streams and re-publish them so others see other people from the chat, etc..

I'm also not sure how much traffic and bandwidth this is gonna consume though and generally, you will need way more than a Stackoverflow question to solve this issue. Best would be to do a full spec of your app and then hire some people to help you build it.

HTH!

Comment: PHP is not the issue actually. I said that I have started with videowhisper plugin. But what the problem is RTMP installations. and I am not sure what I am missing right now. Thats why asked if anyone worked such application before can let me know in detail where changes needed actually.

Thanks for ur suggestion anyway ... :)